# Splitting closed curve data points into subsets of curves

Tags: algorithm, interpolation, numerical-methods, curve, data-fitting

[image]I'm facing an issue with interpolating closed curves. My approach involves dividing the curve into intervals, illustrated by the green rectangles in the attached picture. The goal is to interpolate within each interval in a way that ensures no x-value has more than one corresponding y-value within the set. Once these intervals are interpolated, I plan to connect them to create an approximation of the main curve. I have a dataset consisting of points on this curve. How can I divide this dataset into 'n' subsets? The challenge lies in the fact that the data is sorted by their x-values, preventing a straightforward iteration to select 'length/n' points for each subset.